# How would you encrypt and SQLite db in .net maui?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm, maui

I have used the standard SQLite-net-pcl NuGet package, is there any other NuGet packages that handles encryption?

```
if (_dbConnection == null)
            {
                string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Funds.db3");
                _dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
                await _dbConnection.CreateTableAsync<FundsModel>();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace SQLite-net-pcl package with AQLite-net-sqlcipher.

also replace this line of code:

```
 _dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
```

with this:

```
var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(dbPath, true, "password", postKeyAction: c =>
                {
                    c.Execute("PRAGMA cipher_compatability = 3");
                });
                _dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(options);
```

and run the connection again and that will encrypt all the data in the db.